# Connect-AzureAD : parsing_wstrust_response_failed: Parsing WS-Trust response failed

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am getting the following below error when every time i run my script to connect to Azure Ad via Powershell

```
Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.: parsing_wstrust_response_failed: Parsing WS-Trust response failed
At C:\Azure-AD\Azure-Connect.ps1:10 char:1
+ Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId -credential $MyCredential
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD
```

Below is the script i have created

```
$TenantId = ""
$SecFile = "C:\Azure-AD\Password.txt"
$SecUser = "C:\Azure-AD\UserName.txt"
$MyCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential  -ArgumentList $SecUser,
 (Get-Content $SecFile | ConvertTo-SecureString)

Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId-credential $MyCredential
```

I am using the following line to generate to encrypt my password

```
(Get-Credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\AzureAD\Password.txt"
```

Any solutions on how I can fix the errors and connect to Azure Ad via Powershell

Comment: Do you have any federation with Azure AD configured? AD FS, Okta or something else ?

Comment: You are not providing a username, but a path to a file in `$SecUser`

Comment: The path file has my username  inside it

Comment: We do not have Azure Ad configured, Ivan and we had MFA enabled but that has not been disabled. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: My user is actually configured by OKTA could that be the reason?

Comment: Thank Ivan for pointing it out, the issue was due my user being OKTA. I created another user in Azure and was able to run the script successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

Please use the below script :

```
$tenantID = ""
$secfile = "C:\Azure-AD\Password.txt";
$secuser = "C:\Azure-AD\UserName.txt";
$username = Get-Content $secuser;
$password = Get-Content $secfile |  ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;
$MyCredential = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password);
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantID -credential $MyCredential
```

[image]